# Size of normalizer of abelian subgroup of a $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

Is there something available in the literature which discusses the size of the normalizer of an abelian subgroup of a finite $p$-group?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $N_P(A)>A$ is the only thing you can say (if $A$ is proper).

Comment: Ok. you mean the normalizer condition for p-groups?

Comment: Yes exactly. I can't think of anything else that could hold in full generality.